# Where are my fonts after macOS 10.13.4 update?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, font

Just upgraded High Sierra to macOS 10.13.4.

A bunch of fonts are missing after upgrading to macOS 10.13.4.

What happened to these fonts?

Comment: Please be specific, include the names of the fonts in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bunch of fonts were removed from the base operating system.

- Open FontBook
- Find the font you want to get
- Click "Download"
- Voilà!